# Datagridview not saving changes to DB when Navigator save changes clicked

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

This is a VB.NET, Winforms App, Using EF. On my form I have a datagridview, a databinding source, and a bindingNavigator... I can edit the cells of the datagridview but when I click save changes the value is only saved until I reload the form.?.? Looking at the database table directly I can see the value never actually changes.. Below is the sub that handles the click..

```
Private Sub UnitBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UnitBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    UnitDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
    db.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

From what I have read this seems like all I need to have but obviously its wrong somehow..

Answer (score 0):

I made a work around for it for the time being... I simply use the CellEndEdit event and get the row info from that. Next I get the value of the column that holds the id and update the database from there. Seems like a long way around but is the only way I can get it to write any data at the moment...